# How can I used Func<T,bool> that passed in object?

Tags: c#, wpf, generics, ivalueconverter

I want to create IValueConverter that getting function and object (of some kind) and return bool value.

How can I cast function and parameters in runtime?

```
public object EvaluateByValue(object MyFunc, object parameter)
{
    return MyFunc(parameter);
}
```

For example:

```
Func<int,bool> MyIntFunction =  i=>return i%2;int number = 8;
bool IsEvan = (bool)EvaluateByValue(MyIntFunction,8);
```

and another use can be:

```
Func<string,bool> MyStringFunction = txt=>txt=="Hello";

bool IsWelcome = (bool)EvaluateByValue(MyStringFunction,"Goodbye");
```

Is there any way to cast the "Func" method by the parameter type?

Thanks

Comment: Add sample data and code from where you want to call this method.

Comment: How do you plan to pass both a function and object to the IValueConverter? Do you really mean an IMultiValueConverter? (which can accept multiple parameters)  Or, do you plan on passing one of them as a parameter?

Answer (score 1):

I would change your method to the following:

```
public object EvaluateByValue(Delegate MyFunc, params object[] parameters)
{
    return MyFunc.DynamicInvoke(parameters);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the cast is your only problem, perhaps what you're looking for is:

```
var myFuncDelegate = (Func<object, bool>)parameter;
```

If you want the Func's parameter type to be the same as the given parameter, you would have to use reflection to cast the delegate and execute it.

Answer (score 0):

Well the *minimum* amount of change would be:

```
public object EvaluateByValue(Func<object, object> MyFunc, object parameter)
{
    return MyFunc(parameter);
}
```

or to allow multiple paramaters:

```
public object EvaluateByValue(Func<object[], object> MyFunc, params object[] parameter)
{
    return MyFunc(parameter);
}
```

Although I'm not sure what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this for the function declaration

```
 static K EvaluateByValue<T, K>(Func<T, K> MyFunc, T parameter)
        {
            return MyFunc(parameter);
        }
```

`T` is the parameter type and `K` is the return type

So, let's say you've got this function you want to pass in

```
 static string parameterFunction(string param)
        {
            return param + " World!";
        }
```

you would call it like so

```
var answer = EvaluateByValue<string, string>(parameterFunction, "Hello");
```

And `answer` would be `Hello World!`